# What happens when the Call of Duty 4 - Modern Warfare solo campaign is beaten on a higher difficulty?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I played through and beat the solo campaign of Call of Duty 4 - Modern Warfare on the **Recruit** difficulty when I first purchased the game a long time ago.  I vaguely remember the game telling me to try beating it on a higher difficulty.  Do you get a multiplayer perk or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the only difference is (on 360, possibly on PS3 too) there is an achievement for beating the game on one of the top two difficulty settings, and several achievements for beating groups of missions on the top difficulty setting.

Comment: That's the only difference on PC as well.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've completed the single-player campaign, you get access to a mission called 'The Mile High Club'. When completed at Veteran level, you get a Achievement that's normally the one you need to get the full 1000/1000 on the XBox version.

Answer (score 1):

I've beaten it on Veteran.  There's absolutely no difference other than that it's a HELL of a lot harder.

Comment: The only parts I found hard were defending the computers in the estate and the boat ride out. Compared to MW1, it was easy.